# Change acl of pdf and non-google documents (EDU domain)

Tags: google-apps-script, gdata-api, google-data-api, google-apps-for-education

I'm receiving this error when trying to change file ownership from Google Apps Script (Google Apps for Education):

GData`ServiceException`You can't yet change the owner of this item. (We're working on it.)

The same code works on a Google Apps for Business domain. Is there a limitation for EDU domains?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer in the Google Drive support pages:

> Only Google Apps customers in Premier and Government domains can
>   transfer ownership of a synced or uploaded file (such as a PDF or
>   image file). If you're using Google Drive and Google Docs with a
>   personal account or with a Google Apps for Education account, you
>   can't transfer ownership of a synced or uploaded file.

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494892

Does anyone know why this limitation exists for Education accounts?
Is Google really working on it (as mentioned in the error message)?